# Correctly compare names with different romanization?

Tags: algorithms, natural-language-processing

I am running into a problem in which I have names with different romanization methods, and I need to correctly compare them to see which names match.

An example is romanized Korean variants: Seong vs Sung vs Song are all romanized variants of the same Korean character. A Levenshtein ratio would say that these are all different, but a human would be able to see that they're pretty much the same, i.e. Kyung Sung vs Kyeong Seong. I'd need the method to be able to go beyond just Levenshtein ratio and confidently say that they are an exact match (~1.0) instead of the ~0.8-0.9 that Levenshtein ratio would output.

I read a paper on Thai romanization that suggests Monge-Elkan is quite good if you have names without many typos in them, but goes down drastically if the names have typos. I can't guarantee that the data won't have typos unfortunately, so not sure if there is a better method? Any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot address this without a complete list of character variants. Then you can precompute the legit combinations of all names and perform the comparison against all groups so obtained, keeping the shortest distance.

E.g. to match Kyong to Kyung, perform comparisons to Kyung and Kyeong, resulting in 1 substitution and 1 deletion respectively. Keep the one considered best.

Answer (score 0):

The Soundex algorithm, or some variant of it tailored to the particular features of the Romanisation schemes, could be a good place to start.

Certainly some algorithm that is informed by phonetics and so on, is likely to perform better than an arbitrary algorithm designed to compare strings generally.